# ASP page size limitation

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on a ASP page having search option. After getting search result, wherever i click on any link which calls javascript function, I am getting an error as 'object expected'. (All search result is displayed on single page only and this happens only on large result). When i enabled javascript debugging, it allows me to debug this error scenario in Visual studio. Here What i found is, the ASP page gets loaded is incomplete(clipped inbetween). So the javascript function which gets called is not in this perticular frame as it is written after body tag.

So my question is, Is there any page size limitation for processing ASP or HTML.
(I am using IE browser). Please let me know any more infor needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey I found it.... there is one settings as ASPMaxRequestEntityAllowed in IIS. it was set to 200KB which i modified to 512KB. and paged worked without any problem....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure page size has anything to do with your problem. However if you are using a grid control set EnableViewState="false" this will reduce your page size considerably and speed up any postbacks you may be doing.

Comment: Thanks but I am not using any 'eanbleviewstate' attribute.

Comment: But I am displaying result in a frame